# First order Taylor expansion of matrix function

Tags: taylor-expansion, linear-approximation

In the textbook "Macroeconomic Theory" of Wickens, p. 372, I found the following approximation:

$$\frac{1}{2} \text{tr} A \pm \frac{1}{2} [(\text{tr}A)^2 - 4\text{det}A  ]^{\frac{1}{2}}\approx \left \lbrace \frac {\text{det}A}{\text{tr}A}, \text{tr}A -  \frac {\text{det}A}{\text{tr}A} \right \rbrace $$

which is supposedly derived from a first order Taylor series approximation. Any idea of how this result can be obtained? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What do the braces mean? Also is for any matrix or only a specific size of matrix?

Comment: This is true if $\operatorname{tr}(A)>0$ and $|\det A|$ is significantly smaller than $\operatorname{tr}(A)$. It follows from the approximation that $\sqrt{1-\epsilon}\approx 1-\frac12\epsilon$ for small $\epsilon$.

Comment: user1551 thank you very much for your help!